# Ring buffer data structure

Tags: data-structures, ada

The package `GNAT.Bounded_Buffers` provides a simple implementation of a bounded buffer but unfortunately insertion into the buffer blocks until space is available in the buffer. I am also missing an entry to extract all data stored in the buffer at once.

Before I start to implement my own ring buffer package with the missing functionality I would like to know if such a package may be already available?

Comment: What behavior do you want when the buffer is full? The two options are blocking the writer or over-writing the oldest data. Over-writing is valid if your system only needs to sample the buffer rather than processing every value written to the buffer.

Comment: The oldest data in the buffer should be overwritten.

Comment: How many elements do you want in the buffer if you are sampling the data? If you read the entire buffer at once how do you want to signify the order in which the data is written? I ask because I have found that a sampling buffer with a sizer of 1 element often is all that is needed.

Comment: You might find my article https://sworthodoxy.blogspot.com/2015/05/shared-resource-design-patterns.html to be of some use.

Comment: Also, what happens if you try to read from an empty buffer?

Comment: "`Bounded_Buffer` is declared explicitly as a protected type…" and the API specifies that `Insert` "blocks caller until space is available." The implementation enforces this with an _entry barrier_; your implementation could enforce a different condition.

Comment: Is there a reason the range didn't use a modular type declaration? The indices can wrap around automatically.